# Using fwrite() deletes data

Tags: c, file-io, fwrite

I wrote a very simple file corruptor for fun, but to my surprise, the "corrupted" file ends up being smaller in size than the original.

Here is the corruption function that is supposed to replace bytes but not to delete them:

```
void
corruptor(char *inputname, int percent)
{
  FILE *input;
  FILE *output;
  int filesize;

  char *outputname = append_name(inputname);

  // Duplicate file
  cp(outputname, inputname);

  // Open input and output
  input = fopen(inputname, "r");
  if (input == NULL)
    {
      printf("Can't open input, errno = %d\n", errno);
      exit(0);
    }
  output = fopen(outputname, "w+");
  if (output == NULL)
    {
      printf("Can't open output, errno = %d\n", errno);
      exit(0);
    }

  // Get the input file size
  fseek(input, 0, SEEK_END);
  filesize = ftell(input);

  // Percentage
  int percentage = (filesize * percent) / 100;

  srand(time(NULL));

  for (int i = 0; i < percentage; ++i)
    {
      unsigned int r = rand() % filesize;

      fseek(output, r, SEEK_SET);
      unsigned char corrbyte = rand() % 255;
      fwrite(&corrbyte, 1, sizeof(char), output);

      printf("Corrupted byte %d\n", r);
    }

  fclose(input);
  fclose(output);
}
```

Comment: `man fopen`: *w+     Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if  it  does  not exist,  otherwise  it is truncated.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.* Also, C11 draft standard n1570: *w+ truncate to zero length or create text file for update*

Comment: Thanks @EOF, but w also truncate the file.

Comment: After `fseek(output, r, SEEK_SET);` the output file (with an initial size of 0)  will only be as large as the largest random position you work with.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @WeatherVane

Comment: The output file starts with size 0 becuase you just made it. Any earlier file of that name is destroyed. Unless you write to a file position that is the length of the input file, the output file will be smaller. But you don't, you pick random position for writing to the output file. So that is as big as it will be. MSVC "w+" *Opens an empty file for both reading and writing. If the file exists, its contents are destroyed.*

Comment: @WeatherVane: Actually, I'm not sure you're right either. `fseek()` doesn't cause the file to expand on its own. As far as I can tell, C doesn't even specify what happens if you `fseek()` beyond the end of the file. POSIX does AFAICT, but my `man lseek` suggests that a "hole" is created in the file, so the filesize on disk could be even smaller than your comment suggests.

Comment: @EOF AFAIK when you seek beyond the end of the file and then write, the unwritten intervening positions are filled with `0` but I cannot reference that. But surely the output file will be no larger than that.

Comment: @WeatherVane: `man lseek:` *The lseek() function allows the file offset to be set beyond the end of the file (but this does not change the size of the file).   If  data  is  later written  at  this point, subsequent reads of the data in the gap (a "hole") return null bytes ('\0') until data is actually written into the gap.* My point is that modern filesystems don't store the implicit zeros for the hole to disk, they just count the number of all-zero blocks.

Comment: @WeatherVane I forgot to mention that, after `cp(outputname, inputname);`, output is created and is identical to input.

Comment: @EOF yes I recall that, but the output file will never be as large as the input file, unless the same last position is written.

Comment: @depogoce does that bear out what EOF wrote: there are holes in the file, so it appears smaller but compares the same?

Comment: @WeatherVane: My point is that the output file will likely not be as large as the input file *even if* the same last position is written.

Comment: @EOF see my immediate above comment.

Comment: File properties (Windows) give two stats for file size: size of file and size on disk.

Comment: @WeatherVane: There are people using C on Windows? That's crazytalk.

Comment: @EOF it's a fact: get over it. Windows explorer file properties have nothing to do with C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
output = fopen(outputname, "w+");
```

This deletes the contents of the file, To open the file for reading and writing without deleting the contents, use mode "r+".

Comment: You've fixed it. Thank you @immibis